# Migrating existing Karate project from Version 0.8.0 to 0.9.5

Tags: api, migration, cucumber, version, karate

I'm trying to migrate existing Karate project from 0.8.0 to 0.9.5
but facing some issues like below

1)None of the below imports are working, Need to figure it out equalling ones from 0.9.5
Looking for help from other, who has already tried this

```
import com.intuit.karate.cucumber.CucumberUtils;
import com.intuit.karate.cucumber.FeatureWrapper;
import com.intuit.karate.cucumber.KarateFeature;
import com.intuit.karate.cucumber.KarateJunitAndJsonReporter;
import com.intuit.karate.cucumber.KarateJunitFormatter;
import com.intuit.karate.cucumber.KarateReporter;
import com.intuit.karate.cucumber.KarateRuntime;
import com.intuit.karate.cucumber.KarateRuntimeOptions;
import com.intuit.karate.cucumber.KarateStats;
import com.intuit.karate.filter;
```

2)`import com.intuit.karate.cucumber.CucumberRunner;`- stating as Deprecated already, need to know replacement of this, my baseClass extends CucumberRunner.

3)also need to know replacement for below also

```
import com.intuit.karate.cucumber.FeatureFilePath;
import com.intuit.karate.cucumber.FeatureWrapper;
import com.intuit.karate.ScriptContext;
```

above imports are using in parsing Feature file

```
public static FeatureFilePath parseFeaturePath(File file) {
```

Please suggest tips to get this migration done successfully.

Thank you,
Jay

Comment: Thank you Peter Thomas for Quick Reply. I have already gone through this page : https://github.com/intuit/karate/releases, grabbed Difference Among Versions but I'm looking specifically that, replacement for those classes. as soon as i have update version from 0.8.0 to 0.9.5 in pom.xml, raising this errors. Looking for help on equallavent classes for those raising errors.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, only `KarateStats` was designed as a public API which is replaced by `com.intuit.karate.Results`. And `CucumberRunner` is replaced by `com.intuit.karate.Runner`. These are clearly mentioned in the [release notes for 0.9.0](https://github.com/intuit/karate/releases/tag/v0.9.0).

[image]

The core of Karate was completely written and things like the `KarateFeature` and `FeatureWrapper` don't even exist anymore. I would say whoever decided to use or extend these classes made a very bad decision, and we never documented or encouraged any such approach. All the best !

Comment: Hi Peter Thomas, Thank you so much for suggesting equalling classes, though I have missed in fetch from release Notes. with your suggestions, i'm making good progress in migration. Definitely seek for your help when required. Thanks a lot :)